# Variable start point for Vlookup

Tags: excel

My problem is that I am trying to dynamically change where my vlookup starts. I have a basic working solution of nesting If's and vlookups. Currently the If statements check if Vendor = A etc. and then performs the vlookup. I am concerned about the scalability of this lookups if more vendors are added. A dozen nested if's would be a problem to troubleshoot or update.

I should note that my lookup table is in another workbook so using Indirect isn't a workable option.

My basic data will look like this:

| Vendor | ID | Vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | (lookup result:E) |
| A | 2 | (lookup result:F) |
| B | 3 | (lookup result:F) |
| B | 4 | (lookup result:G) |

The table that I'm looking up from has this structure:

| Vendor A ID | Vendor B ID | Vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | E |
| 2 | 3 | F |
|  | 4 | G |

Comment: Anything we propose will use the vendor and try to match on the title row of your second table.  So the question is, is `Vendor * ID` the way the title row is in you actual data, or is it `* ID` or just `*` where `*` is the vendor name?

Comment: I have freedom to rename the columns. I'm mostly just looking for the overall structure because in my real data, I derive what the vendor is from some other column, but am just stating it here for clarity purposes.

Comment: Apart from my formula-based solution, I also suggest you look into **power query** as you can reshape your lookup table and then use the merge query function in the power query to return the Vehicle code. Let me know if you would like to see a solution using PQ which is built into Excel 2013 and all later versions.

Comment: While I'm going to use your XLookup solution, I am curious about a power query solution since I've only touched that a handful of times.

Comment: @ErikRemkus Given that you will have the source lookup table in a different workbook, in the resulting workbook, you can use the **Get & Transform Data** function under the `Data` tab, load the `LookUp` table from the source workbook, highlight the `Vehicle` column in the PowerQuery Editor, use the `Unpivot Other Columns` function to unpivot the table, then you should have a three-column table showing the Vendor Name, Vendor ID and Vehicle Code in each column. Then you may use the merge function to look up the Vehicle Code by Vendor Name by Vendor ID. Lastly, load the output to a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the title in the second table to match the actual vendor name.

Use nested INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($H:$H,MATCH($B2,INDEX($F:$G,0,MATCH($A2,$F$1:$G$1,0)),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer an alternative solutions than INDEX+MATCH (which I think is simple and efficient enough)

If your version of excel can use **XLOOKUP** function, you can try the following:

Suppose your second table (containing vehicle code) is in a **structured reference table** called `LookUp` such as below (the data in red colour is for testing purpose):

[image: LookUp table]

Suppose your first table (result table) is in range `A1：C6`, in Cell `C2`, you can enter the following formula to look up the vehicle code from the `LookUp` table (drag it down to apply to all cells in this column):

```
=XLOOKUP($B2,XLOOKUP($A2,LookUp[#Headers],LookUp),LookUp[Vehicle])
```

[image: Result table]

Set your lookup table up as a structured reference table and use structured reference in your formula will give more flexibility when there is a change in the lookup table such as adding new columns.

Comment: When I implemented this, I get a #ref error since this my lookup table is in another workbook. The error goes away when I open up the workbook, but that is not ideal for our workflow because multiple people need to work with it at once.

Comment: @ErikRemkus If you want to work with two workbooks, you can add the file location in front of the structured reference each time you need to refer to the content from the `LookUp` table. E.g. instead of using `LookUp[#Headers]`, you need to use `'C:\Users\[Your User Name]\Desktop\[Your Workbook Name].xlsx'!LookUp[#Headers]` in the formula. An easier approach would be setting up the lookup table in the new workbook first and then manually input the **XLOOKUP** formula in your result workbook. Once you close the source workbook, the formula will be updated with file locations automatically.